# In GitLab is it possible to configure a Scheduled Pipeline that runs on all branches periodically?

Tags: gitlab, scheduled-tasks, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery, gitlab-api

I am using GitLab for Git version control and GitLab CI / CD for my automated builds.  Usually, the builds are triggered by Git repository activity but I also have a weekly build to ensure that projects not under active development continue to work.  When there is only a "master" branch on a project, it is easy to ensure a weekly build is run on the latest code.  When there are multiple branches in a project, I would like to repeat the pipeline work for each of them in turn.

What I would like to be able to do is schedule a build (weekly, fortnightly or monthly) that runs on all current branches visible in Git.  Is that possible within GitLab's Continuous Delivery system?

---

The motivation behind doing this is to ensure that external activity, such as tool and library updates, do not introduce an issue without it being promptly visible.  Assuming there are reasonable automated testing, coverage and comprehensive builds for target platforms, a monthly build with the latest tools should highlight the problem promptly.  This is better than an invisible mountain to problems accumulating while a project is shelved for a few years (or months).  Sometimes all that is required is occasional maintenance.

There are only a handful of feature branches and release lines on the projects currently.  I would not expect that number to grow significantly.  There is time enough over a weekend to run the required pipelines dozens if not hundreds of times at present.

---

Ideally, I would like something straightforward to set up.  I cannot see anything in the admin GUI that would allow this at present.  I did look at the API and I can see there is some scope there to script the addition and removal.  Perhaps some script that is run once a month to create new Scheduled pipelines based on git branches is the only way.  A pre-made solution on those lines would be perfectly acceptable.  If nothing exists I might start work on something like that in time.

I am currently running GitLab Community Edition 11.2.3 06cbee3 (GitLab CE 11.2.3).  If there is an Enterprise Edition only answer, that is fine and will add to the justifications of purchasing the EE version.  I would pick at CE one above the EE one though.

Comment: It's unlikely, IMO, that you would actually want to run a nightly pipeline against *all* branches, as you will probably have various idea, feature, etc. branches that are in various states of brokenness. Just worry about `master` and whatever active release branches you have. This should be a low number, able to be configured manually.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I specifically avoided the word nightly as I feel that would be too frequent.  Even weekly is probably more than needed.  Part of the motiviation is to encourage branches that hang around to either be in a good state or get removed.  I have worked places where there were dozens of idea and feature branches left around for years with no one sure if they needed them or not.  When a few were needed it them took a couple of weeks to get them working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a schedule for all branches at once, you have to configure one schedule per branch yourself.

> Perhaps some script that is run once a month to create new Scheduled
>   pipelines based on git branches is the only way.

I would go in that way.

Comment: I probably should have framed the question on the basis that is is possible.  "How do I... automatically?".  Your answer does match my current conclusions.  I will accept it in a few days if no other consensus is reached.